# Limiting length of string displayed in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

new to React so forgive the potentially rookie question, I've just started to try and build an accordion styled component, so that the collapsed content displays a max of 40 characters, and then rest can only be viewed when expanded. The expanding button hasn't been added yet but was hoping someone could direct me on the best approach to limiting the characters to 40?

```
// @flow
import styled from "styled-components";
import chevron from "../Assets/chevron-arrow.svg";

type Props = { className?: string };

const Accordion = styled.div`
  background-color: #e5e9eb;
  height: 56px;
  width: 612px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #27282a;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
`;

const InnerHeading = styled.p`
margin-left: 24px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
font-weight: 600px;
`;

const ExpandableString = ({ attribute, className }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Accordion className={className}><InnerHeading>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat lacinia condimentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus vel pharetra eros. Nullam pellentesque nibh ex, at lobortis augue ultricies sit amet. Praesent viverra nibh in hendrerit molestie. Maecenas laoreet rutrum.</InnerHeading></Accordion>
  );
};



export default ExpandableString;
```

Comment: Would you want it to be 40 as well when zoomed in with large text?

Comment: No not really, basically trying to build an accordion of sorts, so that only the first 40 characters are displayed unless the dropdown is expanded, adding more space for the rest of the content to be displayed in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use js [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
content.substring(0,40) + ' ...'
```